# Certain SO profile pages won't load ("Oops! Something Bad Happened!")

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, 500-server-error, activity

Some SO profile pages won't load at all, others will load but you can't go to the Activity tab, others are absolutely fine.

Examples:

- Me: [Profile **fails for me**, seems to work for others](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder) (including me if I use a different browser and don't log in) | [rep tab **fails**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/157247/t-j-crowder?tab=reputation)
- Tholle: [Profile works](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle) | [rep tab works](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3617886/tholle?tab=reputation)
- gnat: [Profile works](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat) | [rep tab **fails**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/839601/gnat?tab=reputation)
- Jon Skeet: [Profile works](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) | [rep tab **fails**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet?tab=reputation)

Presumably the fact my main profile fails for me but not others has to do with me being signed in as the person whose profile I'm viewing.

(Why did I choose those accounts? I chose my account because, well, that's where I first hit the problem. I chose Tholle at random. I chose gnat because he'd [had a similar problem before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311765/user-profile-page-takes-15-20-seconds-to-load-on-first-load-in-x-minutes#comment1020549_311765). Finally, I chose Jon because he's a long-term, high-rep user with a lot of activity.)

Possibly related:

- [*User profile page takes 15-20 SECONDS to load on first load in X minutes*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/311765/user-profile-page-takes-15-20-seconds-to-load-on-first-load-in-x-minutes)
- [*Planned maintenance scheduled for July 14, 2018 at 13:00 UTC (9AM US/Eastern)*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312374/planned-maintenance-scheduled-for-july-14-2018-at-1300-utc-9am-us-eastern)

Comment: I can't repro the error on your main profile page, but the rep tab fails on you, gnat, and Jon.

Comment: @NathanTuggy - Interesting. It still fails for me on my main browser where I'm logged in, but works if I use a different browser and don't log in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be fixed. Last week, we made changes to the query to adjust a couple of indexes and 'hey, it worked', but then we did the maintenance yesterday which failed the database over to a different server and guess what it decided to stop working as expected.

All of the indexes were the same, but the SQL Engine picked a different execution plan for the page which was not the plan we wanted. The good news is that last week, I turned on [query store for SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-2017) which captures different execution plans for queries. The query store captured both the good and the bad plan, and one of the nice things about this is it lets me tell the server to use the good plan. I just forced the plan for the query and it should be loading now.

Comment: From the little I understood it means that when you'll "fail the database over to a different server" again, it might pick the wrong plan again (since you forced it only on the current server) and this bug will just happen again. Is this correct? If so, why not just get rid of the bad execution plan so it can't be picked up in the future?

Comment: @ShadowWizard it’s possible that would happen. Since it’s the weekend I didn’t dig in too much on this. My goal was to get the page to load for the time being, I’ll look closer next week. The hope would be that since we sync things via availability groups, the query store selections would sync as well but I’ll have to look later.

Comment: Working great this morning, thanks!