# Trying to view Jon Skeet reputation causes 500 error

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

There's [this link](https://stackexchange.com/users/3906943/adelin?tab=reputation) that shows your reputation across all networks (just change the id with  the appropriate one. `me` doesn't work).

Trying to view [Jon Skeet's](https://stackexchange.com/users/11683/jon-skeet?tab=reputation)... well, unsurprisingly, the server doesn't face the request.

[image]

Comment: There's a good chance to DoS SE with meta readers trying now :)

Comment: Sorry--can't help myself--but that picture and its caption ("Something Bad Happened!") is so freaking ADORABLE

Comment: Most likely same root issue as [this other bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/312639/certain-so-profile-pages-wont-load-oops-something-bad-happened), and the fix wasn't applied in stackexchane.com yet.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not the same root cause as the previous issue, but it should be resolved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This should be resolved now. Over the last couple of weeks we have been doing some query tuning which was applied to all the databases across the network, but SQL was being very stubborn and didn't want to use the plan we were expecting. This morning after digging through many execution plans, we resolved the issue forcefully.

On a more technical level, SQL Server was basically trying to perform something similar a `CROSS JOIN` on rep history which resulted in it reading more rows than it actually needed, so we resorted to using [query hint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-join?view=sql-server-2017) to force a `LEFT HASH JOIN`. Miraculously, it worked as we wanted and now the graph loads.

Comment: Reading this reminded me of my kids refusing to do stuff (e.g. dressing, brushing teeth) and we (parents) have to force them into it. :D